# How to update formulas referring to different files wih the newest sheet added to them in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, excel-formula

I have several Excel files that represent Projects. Every month there is a new sheet that appears with the updated information for the current month. I need to combine them in one sheet as a summery overview.

My problem comes when from the fact that I am downloading the project files on my PC and the formula dragging information from them refers to the folder and the sheet. Let's say now we are in October and the formula is:

```
IFERROR('[Project (1).xlsm]Oct 17'!$E$24;" ").
```

However, when November comes I will need to update Oct 17 to Nov 17 which is huge manual work.

Is there a way to do that with a drop down menu related to some VBA macro? For example there is an Intro page on which you can choose from a drop down menu the certain month and all the formula paths are updated based on that.

Comment: Where are the formulas located? All in one column? In specific columns? An image of the data you are working with would help and any formulas/code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following where you run a sub to find formulas that contain a specific string stored in a variable. I am calling it FindMonth. You search and replace this string with the desired month, ReplaceMonth. Note i am including the end part of the year to the string e.g. "Nov 17". When running each month you just edit these two lines:

```
 FindMonth = "Oct 17" 'Edit for month you want to find
 ReplaceMonth = "Nov 17" 'Edit for month you want to replace with
```

You could associate the procedure with a command button and use inputbox prompts for the FindMonth and ReplaceMonth and assign the value input to the variables instead.

You define the area for replacement in the Set searchRange. 
As i don't know what area you are searching i have used 2 functions by Ron De Bruin to find the last used row and column in the sheet variable ws (you would amend to the sheet you want to change formulas in) and said the search range is from A1 to the last used cell i.e. lastrow, lastcolumn.

```
 Set searchRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(LastRow(ws), LastCol(ws)))
```

This is to prevent looping through every cell in the sheet.

You would need to amend to which ever sheet you are actually replacing in.

Also, consider what kind of error handling you want to include in case lookup sheet is not present in lookup workbook (e.g.Dec 17 sheet missing) or workbook is not open...... I have used `On Error Resume Next` for now. You might choose something like `On Error GoTo ErrHandler` and in the ErrHandler have a `CASE Err.Number 1004 ...do something........`

```
  Option Explicit


  Sub ReplaceFormula()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change as appropriate to your sheet name

    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Dim FindMonth As String
    Dim ReplaceMonth As String

    FindMonth = "Oct 17"
    ReplaceMonth = "Nov 17"

    Set searchRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(LastRow(ws), LastCol(ws)))

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error Resume Next 'Sheet may not be present or source workbook may not be open

    For Each cell In searchRange.Cells

        If InStr(1, cell.Formula, FindMonth) > 0 Then cell.Formula = Replace(cell.Formula, FindMonth, ReplaceMonth)

    Next cell

    On Error GoTo 0

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you QHarr, that works. However now I get a pop up window for all the lines which I created as placeholders for the projects that are not yet there but may occur - for example I have only 15 projects and I have updated the formula to look for another 5. For those 5 I get a pop up message asking which file to open and provide a path. Can I integrate in the VBA a way to always cancel those pop ups?

Comment: I have edited the code and added    Application.EnableEvents = False at start and set to true at end. See if that works and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I typically do a find replace for this - I also have a monthly job where I have this scenario. (You can restrict the search replace to highlighted cells if required).
Also, the reference to the directory should dissappear if you load the files in memory.
With the above info you could script this - I do find the search replace takes a few seconds of a multi-hour job so I haven't bothered automating. Hit F2 and select what you want to replace and paste that into the find box (e.g. `]Oct 17` and then replace with `]Nov 17`